# Style a div without removing padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have a question that I can't for the life of me figure out. I have this piece of HTML-code:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
                    <li class="twolines"><div id="vadarmindfulness" class="active">Vad är mindfulness</div>
```

And this CSS-code to style it:

```
#dropdown li{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-weight: 600;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
list-style-type:none;
margin-bottom:20px;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 130px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;

background-color: #b4cc95;

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b4cc95), to(#a5d06e));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b4cc95,  #a5d06e);
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b4cc95', endColorstr='#a5d06e');
}
```

When one of the list items are clicked, an "active" class gets added to it. That styling is just a green background as of now. However, this only gets applied to a part of the li - the div around the text, and not the whole thing since I use a padding. How would I go about making the whole thing go green?

I didn't quite get this jsfiddle to work, but if you look at the top list item you'll understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hkrzv/

Thanks in advance

Nigerian Warlord

Comment: Can you apply `.active` on the `<li>` instead of the inner `<div>`?

Comment: The JSfiddle probably isn't working (at least partly) because you haven't loaded JQuery.

Comment: I can't find the above mentioned 'partial' effect even after adding jQuery, am i missing something..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.active` class to `li` : 
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hkrzv/5/)**

and do some changes in js:

```
 $('.info_box li').removeClass('active');
 $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

**Updated:**  **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hkrzv/10/)** fixed in chrome.

Comment: I bet that the demo you posted is not what the OP wants, the `width` of the list items should be equal.

Comment: @kingking : all the list items are equal here.

Comment: I think this exactly what @sjc7375 is needed. and if it doesn't then definitely his question needs some alteration :D

Comment: Sorry, I tested it in Opera and Chrome, both showed the first item's width is shorter than the remaining ones'

Comment: Here is the snapshot https://sites.google.com/site/thecabinet3/home/files-store/clgt.png?attredirects=0

Comment: Looks like you tested it only in FireFox but sorry for you that all IE 10, Chrome 33, Opera 20 and even Maxthon render it like as the image I posted above

Comment: I'm using Chrome and the width is not equal to the other li elements.